# Java : How to add an int to digits in an alphanumeric string and return the output

Tags: java

Trying to increment the digits in an alphanumeric string by a number n and return the result with the increased digits in the same position in the string index. If the digit is 9, the output should wrap to 0, 1, 2, 3,.... and so on to 9
`ie String input = "abc123de45"
           n = 2
          print = "abc345de67"

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.inputString.length(); i++) {
    char tempInp = this.inputString.charAt(i);

            if (Character.isDigit(tempInp)) {
                sumDigit = tempInp + n;
            }
            }


        }  
    return sumDigit;
    }
```

Comment: What happens if the digit is 9?

Comment: We also need a [mcve] to see where you're going wrong.

Comment: The simple outline is: convert the string to a char array; find and update the digits; construct a new string from the char array. You can't operate directly on the input string, because strings are immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of a `StringBuilder` and converting the `char` to the relevant `int` value

```
String inputString = "abc123de45";
int n = 2;

StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder ();

for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {

    char tempInp = inputString.charAt(i);

    if (Character.isDigit(tempInp)) {
        buf.append ((tempInp -'0') + n);
    }
    else {
        buf.append(tempInp);
    }   
}

System.out.println(buf.toString());
```

**output**

```
abc345de67
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the StringBuilder to update the string when the if statement is true.

```
public static StringBuilder numericInt(String a,int b)
{
    StringBuilder c = new StringBuilder(a);

    for (int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++) {

        char tempInp = c.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isDigit(tempInp)) {
            int temp=(c.charAt(i)-'0')+b;
            c.setCharAt(i,(char)(temp+'0'));

        }
        }

    return c;
    }  

}
```

Comment: The StringBuilder was extremely helpful as I was having issues with type mismatch. Thanks